# Detecting collision between an object inside a movie clip that is in an array vs another array of objects

Tags: arrays, flash, collision-detection, movieclip, actionscript-3

Simply,

I have randomly placed and moving movie clips that will call victims And I Have another set of random Moving movie clips that have an attack animation I will call them assailants.

Victims wander randomly among Assailants an at random times the Assailants will shoot out a lightning bolt movie clip to attack the victims. It is at this point I am attempting to check for a collision between the victims and the assailants lightning Bolts.

Both types are in separate array's and I have before checked an array vs an array without a problem I have also checked static object vs an array objects internal MC without an issue. However I am Stuck when checking array vs array objects internal MC.

Code:

```
for(var j:int=0;j<NormalBubbleArray.length;j++){

for(var k:int=0;k<LightningStormArray.length;k++){

if(NormalBubbleArray[j].hitTestObject(LightningStormArray[k]).upbolt){
trace("hit")

NormalBubbleArray.removeAt([j]);
LightningStormArray.removeAt([k]);

}
}
}
```

I have also Tried

```
 if(NormalBubbleArray[j].hitTestObject(LightningStormArray[k]).upbolt)
```

and 10 other ways to try and write it. Still no luck not sure if its my loop or collision detection at this point. It gives no errors when running so I assume my Syntax is Ok.
Thanks In Advance.

Update: I was tinkering with it and realized I had it wrapped in a try catch so I was not seeing the error. now my issue is this.

```
for(var j = 0; j<NormalBubbleArray.length;j++){

for(var k = 0; k<LightningStormArray.length;k++){

     if((LightningStormArray[k]).upbolt hitTestPoint(NormalBubbleArray [j]), true){
trace("hit")
(NormalBubbleArray [j]).removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, ChildMouse);
NormalBubbleArray.removeAt([j]);
LightningStormArray.removeAt([k]);

}

}

}
```

Still Compiles but when it comes time to detect I get The following error in the output.

TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
at BubblesReloaded_fla::MainTimeline/CollisionControl()

Help is appreciated.. I am still tinkering with it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it !

Tricky Devil.

The debuger kept pointing to the hittest line and it had nothing to do with the actual line it hilighted but what was inside the if statment that caused the issue.

```
var Lstormpoints:int = 0;
for(var j = 0; j<NormalBubbleArray.length;j++){
for(var k = 0; k<LightningStormArray.length;k++){
if(LightningStormArray[k].upbolt.hitTestPoint(NormalBubbleArray [j]), true){
trace("bubble is hit")
NormalBubbleArray [j].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, ChildMouse);
NormalBubbleArray [j].gotoAndPlay(10)/// was (NormalBubbleArray [j]).gotoAndPlay(10) // was causing an error
NormalBubbleArray.removeAt([j]);
LightningStormArray.removeAt([k]);

}

}

}
```

What threw me off was that the debugger kept pointing to the if statement as the error. What I did not catch is it was trying to tell me that it was an error inside the if statement. I figured it out after some heavy tracing I Noticed that it was detecting collision but the Bubble was not acting as if it got hit giving me the illusion that it was not detecting hit. the gotoAndPlay line animates the death and sadly that was the line with the issue.. just happy I got it going.